# The repository Jammy Release does not have a Release file

Tags: ubuntu, ros2

im following this instruction on Humble Documentation [https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

and im having this error in the installation of the ROS Packages when doing `sudo apt update` in the installing of ROS Packages step

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS since its the supported version for Humble as said by the docs on my Raspberry Pi 4

I have done it step by step and checking first what the required or compatible stuff first but its always have that error so i cant run the `sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop`

Comment: are you sure the `Setup Sources` has been done without errors? you are probably missing something there

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the advice. Looks like I really did miss something on the Setup Sources. Its one of the Y/N prompt. I probably missed it out of frustration on the error.

Answer (score 0):

This error normally means that you are either using a distribution where this package is unavailable or that you haven't set your `apt` source list correctly.

Go through the documentation again in `Setup Sources` to ensure all the stops were done successfully. Sometimes there are unrelated broken packages that make your `sudo apt update` command fail.

Answer (score 0):

I used
`ls /etc/apt/sources.list.d` then `sudo rm -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jonathonf-ubuntu-gcc-jammy.list`
Worked for me